# I cannot get the uploaded file returned using codeignter3 fileupload()

Tags: file-upload, codeigniter-3

I have the following code for file upload in the corresponding model file of codeigniter3.

```
$config['upload_path']      = './assets/img/report/';
        $config['allowed_types']    = 'txt|odt|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|docx';
        $config['file_name']        = $this->id;
        $config['overwrite']        = true;
        $config['max_size']         = '150000';
        
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
            return $this->upload->data('file_name');
        }
        return default.jpg;
```

The corresponding view file has the following code

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="file">Attachment</label>
                    <input class="form-control-file"
                    type="file" name="file" />
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        <?php echo form_error('file') ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

But the code always returns default.jpg. How can I fix to return the uploaded file correctly. I use CI3 in Debian 11 running xampp8.1

Answer (score -1):

```
**Configure your upload path**
After upload this will send you upload data or the upload error
$config = array(
  'upload_path' => "./assets/img/report/",
  'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
  'overwrite' => TRUE,
  'max_size' => "2048000",
  'max_height' => "768",
  'max_width' => "1024"
 );
 $this->load->library('upload', $config);
 if($this->upload->do_upload())
 {
   $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
   return $data;
 }
 else
 {
   $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

 }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).